# Determining the number of yellow pixels in land?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have the below image. I want to determine how many yellow(ish) pixels there are and the percentage of pixels in within the country that are yellow.

So, i need to disregard the sea, france and southern ireland.

Here is my attempt, but I have no idea how to disregard the stuff outside of the country

Also, how can we determine the size in Miles of each Pixel?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('covvv.png')

fiveg = 0
other = 0
sea = 0

for p in im.getdata():
    if p[0] > 150 and p[1] > 150 and p[2] < 150: 
        fiveg += 1
    elif p[0] == 170 and p[1] > 218 and p[2] < 255: 
        sea += 1
    else:
        other += 1
print('5g=' + str(fiveg)+', other='+str(other) + ', sea = 0' + str(sea))
print('%coverage= ' + str((fiveg/other)*100))
```

[image]

Comment: The sea counts are very low, so I don't think it's working well. It's 1494 pixels only.